# node.js mongoose can't update some fields

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i am trying to update a mongodb collection without success on some value, its update one field and not the other , 
here is my code , 
the schema :

```
var clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
emailaddress: {type: String, index: {unique: true}}
, firstname: String
, lastname: String
, domainname: String
, company: String
, password: String
, plan: String
, datePayment: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
, experationPayment: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

the code used to update the collection

```
model.findById(id, function (error, data) {
                    if (error) {
                        ...
                    }
                    else {
                        if (!data) {
                           ...
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('data before:', data);
                            var date = new Date();
                            var expTime = data.experationPayment;
                            var comp = new Date();
                            if (date.getTime() > expTime.getTime()) {
                                comp = date;
                            }
                            else {
                                comp = expTime;
                            }
                            comp.setMonth(comp.getMonth() + month);
                            data.plan = plan;
                            data.datePayment = date;
                            data.experationPayment = comp;
                            console.log('data after:', data);
                            data.save(function (error) {
                            if (!error) {
                                   console.log('plan successfully updated ');                                 res.redirect('/dashboard?message=plan successfully updated');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        res.json({
                                            message: 'error your plan wasnt saved.'
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

and here is the console result , with mongoose debug included

> Mongoose: clients.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("57aa0403b8f3786d09d8c626") }) { fields: undefined }  
>   data before: { datePayment: 2016-08-09T18:03:07.501Z,
>     experationPayment: 2016-09-09T16:37:34.654Z,
>     plan: 'starter',
>     __v: 0,
>     password: 'a',
>     emailaddress: 'a',
>     lastname: 'a',
>     firstname: 'a',
>     _id: 57aa0403b8f3786d09d8c626 }
>   data after: { datePayment: 2016-08-09T18:46:10.131Z,
>     experationPayment: 2017-09-09T16:37:34.654Z,
>     plan: 'starter',
>     __v: 0,
>     password: 'a',
>     emailaddress: 'a',
>     lastname: 'a',
>     firstname: 'a',
>     _id: 57aa0403b8f3786d09d8c626 }
>   Mongoose: clients.update({ _id: ObjectId("57aa0403b8f3786d09d8c626") }) { '$set': { datePayment: new Date("Tue, 09 Aug 2016 18:46:10 GMT") } }  
>   plan successfully updated 
>   Mongoose: clients.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("57aa0403b8f3786d09d8c626") }) { fields: undefined }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the problem , `var expTime = data.experationPayment;` 
expTime is a string object not a date object, the code 
should be `var expTime = new Date(data.experationPayment);`

and now i could use `expTime.getTime()`